# re-organizing Array (Transpose)

Tags: ruby, arrays

For an array that looks like:

```
arr = [["name1","name2","name3"],["address1","address2","address3"],["phone1","phone2","phone3"]]
```

I would like to re-arrange it so that it looks like:

```
arr = [["name1","address1","phone1"],["name2","address2","phone2"], ...
```

Current method is:

```
name = arr[0]
add = arr[1]
phone = arr[2]
arr = name.zip(add,phone)
```

which works, but when I have over ten nested arrays within an array, I have ten lines of defining which is which, just to use zip later.

I hope someone can show me a better way of handling this.

EDIT:

I originally had "Phone1","Phone2", as my initial array (uppercase) and "phone1", "phone2" as my transposed array.

This wasn't intended so I edited it, but with my original post Sawa's answer handles the transpose & the UPPERCASE to lowercase.

Also found the documentation here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose

Comment: Is the conversion `"Phone1"` to `"phone1"` really intended?

Comment: My bad! will edit right away.. ><

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to the original question:

```
arr.transpose.map{|a| a.map(&:downcase)}
```

An answer to a different question after OP's edit:

```
arr.transpose
```

Comment: +1. But I suspect the `downcase` part is just a mistake in the question. After all, the example code does not `downcase`.

Comment: @undur_gongor I just follow what the OP wrote as they are expecting. It is the OP's responsibility. You are right about the OP's code. It does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: @sawa Thanks! I didn't know what this "re-organizing" was called.. as per your code, I've looked at the official doc and found the "transpose" method [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose) However, It also seems to work with just .transpose. Could you elaborate on a reason to use the following codes with .map? Thanks!!

Comment: @Rok transpose only arranges the structure of the array. It does not change the letter case for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
arr = arr.shift.zip(*arr)
```

this code uses the first element of the `arr` while removing it from `arr` (via [`shift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-shift)), than it uses the [`splat`](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) operator to zip it with the rest of the arrays in the array.

Comment: That will not give what the OP wants.

Comment: @sawa - it is a generalization of what he actually _does_ (and claims to work for him)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - you mean `arr[0].zip(*arr[1..-1])`, and since `arr` is overridden by the OP anyway - it is a more succinct way to do the same thing.

Comment: @sawa Short code,, *is not always good*. `#shift` will destroy data. I will not take the *risk* in my code.

Comment: @UriAgassi Yes.. I forgot to *splat* it. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - like many things in ruby  - there is more than one way to skin a cat...

Comment: @UriAgassi Humm.. But *don't destroy data, unless you really need it*.